# Remove all subscribers from the master all subscribers list

Tags: marketing-cloud

Is it possible to remove all subscribers from **the master all subscribers list** with a single request?

I understand that subscribers can be individually removed using DELETE `https://www.exacttargetapis.com/email/v1/subscribers/[ID]`

Issue with individually deleting subscribers is concern about rate limiting because of > 50,000 subscribers on list.

Comment: What is the use case for this?  If this is a one time clean-up that needs to happen, then using the UI to delete the subscribers may be easier.  Create  list, copy all of your subscribers the list, then delete the list selecting the option to delete all subscribers when deleting the list.  There is no similar option available via an API that I am aware of.

Answer (score 2):

Pretty sure you can't delete all subscribers on the All Subscribers list all at once.  If it was another list, you can delete the List Object, which will delete all of the subscribers in it.

Here's a sample SOAP envelope.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:a="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
   <s:Header>
      <a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">Delete</a:Action>
      <a:MessageID>urn:uuid:cec6826f-1ac3-4559-934b-a5ad8e081c3c</a:MessageID>
      <a:ReplyTo>
         <a:Address>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/role/anonymous</a:Address>
      </a:ReplyTo>
      <a:To s:mustUnderstand="1">https://webservice.s4.exacttarget.com/Service.asmx</a:To>
      <o:Security xmlns:o="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" s:mustUnderstand="1">
         <u:Timestamp u:Id="_0">
            <u:Created>2015-01-30T15:29:13.355Z</u:Created>
            <u:Expires>2015-01-30T15:34:13.355Z</u:Expires>
         </u:Timestamp>
         <o:UsernameToken u:Id="uuid-3bd5c867-ef2e-4768-a5e7-3a119b1a8765-11">
            <o:Username><!-- Removed--></o:Username>
            <o:Password><!-- Removed--></o:Password>
         </o:UsernameToken>
      </o:Security>
   </s:Header>
   <s:Body xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <DeleteRequest xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
         <Options>
            <SaveOptions />
         </Options>
         <Objects xsi:type="List">
            <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true" />
            <ObjectID xsi:nil="true" />
            <CustomerKey>aspriggs-test-list</CustomerKey>
         </Objects>
      </DeleteRequest>
   </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```